# Why does Deadpool say "You're welcome, Canada," after shooting Ryan Reynolds in the end credits?

Tags: dialogue, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool-2

In the end credits scene, Deadpool goes back in time to change a few things using Cable's time traveling technology. He goes to the apartment building where a 10-year younger Ryan Reynolds sits holding the Green Lantern script in his hands. Deadpool shoots him in the head and says

> You're welcome, Canada.

What is the reference behind this line? What does it mean?

Comment: So Deadpool is evil enough to murder a ten-year-old child merely to prevent the child from causing minor movie embarrassment to the child's country in the future, and expects that the child's country will thank him for murdering a citizen?  This sounds like Deadpool is a villain instead of a hero.

Comment: @M.A.Golding "ten years young**er**", not "ten years **old**". Ryan Reynolds is 40-something, thus he would have been 30-something. - But I don't see a difference. Why is one worse than the other?

Comment: @M.A.Golding Deadpool is a textbook example of an *anti*hero.

Comment: @M.A.Golding In addition to being an anti-hero, Deadpool has a lot of dark comedy in it. The murder of the younger Ryan Reynolds is a joke. Perhaps a joke some will find in poor taste, but it's not meant as a serious, heroic act at all.

Comment: @M.A.Golding i don't think i've ever heard anyone refer to deadpool as a hero before.

Comment: @M.A.Golding Are you trolling us, or do you really have *no idea* who Deadpool is, and have never seen the [clip in question](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iiWUwStpdZI&frags=pl%2Cwn)? By the way others, the rest of that mid-credits scene is declared canon by the producers, so cuddlebear and Vanessa are indeed saved, and we won't be seeing the merc without a mouth again.  Or Ryan Reynolds as Green Lantern.

Comment: @ToddWilcox If any given joke is NOT in poor taste, you can safely bet it's also not a Deadpool joke.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Ryan Reynolds has repeatedly said that he is less than happy with his appearance in the 2011 "Green Lantern" movie - he even admits that he has [never seen it](https://mashable.com/2018/05/02/ryan-reynolds-green-lantern-never-watched-deadpool-2/).

> Ryan Reynolds provided this explanation to EW, highlighting how although there were a lot of people working hard to make Green Lantern successful, Warner Bros was more concerned with releasing the movie rather than making sure the script was perfected before starting. That meant there was never an opportunity to nail down what the movie's tone was supposed to be, making the final product feel generic

So Deadpool, by killing Ryan Reynolds (a Canadian born in Vancouver) before he accepted his role in the Green Lantern, saved the whole country from the embarrassment of a Canadian actor in the movie.

Answer (score 43):

**Ryan Reynolds is Canadian by birth**, therefore, he uses this line as a reference. He was born in **Vancouver, British Columbia**, Canada.
 He is not very fond of the *Green Lantern* movie as is seen in many of his interviews. He also stated it in Deadpool first movie when he said that **don't make the suit green or animated**. He thought that it was a mistake to take that role and accept that script.
 So, *Deadpool 2* has this scene where Deadpool shoots Ryan Reynolds reading *Green Lantern* script. Thus, Canada his home country is saved from the embarrassment of having him as its lead hero.

Answer (score 3):

Green Lantern was embarrassingly poor quality for Reynolds work.  He apologized to Canadians (his native country) for being involved in such a lousy project by killing Green Lantern in an unceremonious way.

We said thank you.